# How to sync between ProgressDialog and text appearance?

Tags: android, progress-bar

i got this progress dialog code:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}.start();
```

and i got text that will apear after some httprequest actions:

> editText2.setText(stringEr);

how do i sync between them? i want that the text will be hidden untill the progress will finish

tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Handlers to update your UI. A little modification here,

```
new Thread() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                           //Instead of sleep, call your http request method here. 
                           handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                         } 

                         catch (Exception e)
                          {

                          Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

                          }
                           // dismiss the progress dialog
                           progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

              }.start();
```

And create a handler in onCreate(),

```
 Handler handler=new Handler()
{
public void handleMEssage(Message msg)
{
 if(msg.what==0)
editText2.setText(stringEr);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that and you can hide `in OnPreExecute Method` i mean when asynctask in started and show in `OnPostExecute method.` after complete the progress.

Answer (score 1):

Android skip the painful Threading concept, Use `Asyntask` class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
private class UIOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         //show dialog
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //collect data
            return null;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           //dismiss dialog
           //update UI
      }

  }
```

Comment: can i use EditText and stuff in "AsyncTask"? because i got error "the method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type UIOperation"

BTW, i cant set it as private, it says: "Illegal modifier for the class UIOperation; only public, abstract & final are permitted"

Comment: refer http://pcfandroid.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/http-post-with-asynctask-android-tutorial/